# English Language Till or Until

Tags: till-until

I will be away until this Sunday.  I will be available Sunday afternoon 2 PM to 3 PM.

Please correct this if there are any corrections required. Kindly explain the rule for help in understanding its use.

Comment: You realise that the title of the question mentions "till" and "until" but your sentence does not.

Comment: I am going to presume that you think you should place "till/until" *before* the Sunday as in `I will be available until Sunday afternoon, 2 p.m to 3 p.m.` Is that correct?

Comment: You need to explain to us what exactly you want to say. Are you available all day on Sunday until 3 PM, or are you availble *only* from 2 to 3 pm. It is not clear. Note that there are many ways to write the acronyms "am" and  "pm"